# Entropy change due to surroundings?

Tags: thermodynamics, work, entropy, vacuum, ideal-gas

What is the entropy generated by opening up a vacuum chamber of volume $V$ to the atmosphere? (let's say with some constant ambient pressure $P_{atm}$)

I was reading about [Joule expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion), but it doesn't seem to apply as easily in this case since the environment always stays at a constant $P_{atm}$ and more so seems to have a rather "infinite" volume that isn't really much affected by expanding into some small additional space $V$ of a vacuum chamber. So, the $(V_f/V_i)$ or $(P_i/P_f)$ terms in the formula for free/isothermal expansion entropy there always just tend to 1 thus leading to zero entropy generation (per the formulas there). But, this is clearly an irreversible process, since gas wouldn't spontaneously exit out on its own and recreate the vacuum after filling up the chamber!

Also, in order to create a vacuum of volume $V$ in the first place -- we'll need to perform $W = P_{atm}V$ amount of work (e.g, raising a piston originally at the bottom end of a cylinder). However, as the surroundings "fill up" a vacuum, the pressure inside $V$ starts to rise and soon it becomes harder and harder for the surroundings to "push" each additional unit of gas in (since it's no longer expanding against a pure vacuum $P_{internal} = 0$). So, does that mean some work is actually done by the environment against the vacuum chamber as well? (Maybe, even temporarily "heating up" some of the gas inside as well, adiabatically?)

On one hand, if filling up the chamber was a reversible process, we could probably "extract" $W=P_{atm}V$ amount of work back from the environment filling the chamber back up. But, in our case of "just opening a valve" to let air back in, the environment initially does no work expanding against a pure vacuum $P_{internal} = 0$, and only at the very end would have to try to push gas against a $P_{internal} = P_{atm}$ (when the chamber is essentially already filled up!). In essence, only doing what looks like $W = P_{atm}V/2$ onto the system instead...

Comment: The answer to your question depends on whether the vacuum change is insulated or not from the remainder of the air in the room.,  Is the vacuum changer insulated?

Comment: @ChetMiller Did you mean vacuum "charger"? As in, what's originally pulling the vacuum? (not sure what you mean by vacuum "changer")

Comment: I meant chamber.

Comment: @ChetMiller Ahh, good point! I think if the chamber is insulated, the environment could probably perform up to $P_{atm}V$ (reversible) work and so "heat up" the chamber then by $P_{atm}V / (nC_v)$ above ambient temperature via adiabatic compression. And since there's no heat transfer, then it seems no entropy will be generated either. On the other hand, *without insulation*, it seems the $P_{atm}V$ originally used to create the vacuum would ("eventually") just be converted into heat and thus generate $P_{atm}V/T$ amount of entropy instead...

Comment: @ChetMiller In the [Otto cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_cycle), this may also be how the intake stroke may contribute to "engine braking" as well  -- consuming kinetic energy from the drivetrain to expand a [manifold vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold_vacuum) against atmospheric pressure, and then (partially) dissipating this work as heat via the [inrush of air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inlet_manifold) from the environment...

Comment: With regard to your next-to-last comment, entropy would be generated in the valve between the surroundings and the chamber.  Would you like me to an answer to determine the entropy change for that case?

Comment: @ChetMiller Sure, would be interesting to see how the valve setups could affect that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [great twist](https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article-abstract/67/8/712/1043246/An-easy-to-perform-but-often-counterintuitive?redirectedFrom=fulltext) on the [Joule-expansion or free-expansion problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion). We’re familiar with the result there that the average temperature is ultimately unchanged, as the total gas does no work on anything (it’s adjacent to a vacuum) and no heating occurs. As you note, entropy is generated because this dispersion is irreversible.

The notable twist here is that the gas being pushed into the box certainly has work done on it by the atmosphere. We conclude (and experimentally verify) that that gas heats up. (In balance, the atmosphere cools down, but this is negligible because the atmosphere is large.) Heat transfer then equalizes the temperature, producing the free-expansion outcome.

How much entropy is generated? Just replace the free expansion with an easier-to-analyze process that produces the same state. You’ve already done half of this—reversible collection of work through quasistatic expansion—so just tack on the step of irreversibly dumping that energy magnitude back in as thermal energy (by passing electrical work through a resistor, for example).  Follow me?

Comment: So, by energy conversation, if it took $P_{atm}V$ work to create the vacuum in the first place, and the environment performs only $P_{atm}V/2$ work by filling it up, I suppose the "other half" $P_{atm}V/2$ must then be lost as heat? Which it seems would initially generate $P_{atm}V/(2T)$ amount of entropy, and then, after a while, another $P_{atm}V/(2T)$ once the system returns to ambient temperature? So, *overall*, we put in $P_{atm}V$ work to create the vacuum, then by opening the valve, *eventually* lose up to $P_{atm}V$ as heat, ultimately generating a total $P_{atm}V/T$ amount of entropy?

Comment: The reversible work that would be done to fill the vacuum chamber is $P_{atm}V$, not $P_{atm}V/2$. I agree that the entropy generation is $P_{atm}V/T$.

Comment: The *reversible* work would be $P_{atm}V$ (perhaps if the air was let in very slowly through a tiny pinhole or so), but would an *irreversible* path perform less work? If so, would that potentially mean some $P_{atm}V$ applied is lost as heat thus generating entropy? Although, once everything returns to the ambient $T$ and $P_{atm}$, I would then imagine all of that $P_{atm}V$ applied by the environment to be converted into heat with likewise $P_{atm}V/T$ of entropy in turn (per $\delta Q = TdS$ if I'm not mistaken, although I'm not sure if that only applies in special circumstances)...

Comment: The details of how the entropy generation is partitioned between occurring during the gas movement vs. occurring during any heat transfer depend on how the gas enters the container.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that the "surroundings" consists of a very large room (compared to the chamber volume) surrounding the chamber.  Let the temperature and pressure in the room be $T_{ext}$ and $P_{ext}$, respectively, let the volume of the insulated chamber be V, and let the number of moles entering the chamber through the valve be n.

For the air that enters the chamber, it follows from the 1st law of thermodynamics that $$nC_v(T-T_{ext})=P_{ext}V_{injected}=nRT_{ext}$$The solution to this equation for the final temperature T is $$T=\gamma T_{ext}$$ The final pressure is $P=P_{ext}$.  So the change in entropy of the gas that has entered the chamber is $$\Delta S_C=nC_p\ln{\gamma}=\frac{p_{ext}V}{RT}C_p\ln{\gamma}=\frac{p_{ext}V}{T_{ext}}\frac{\ln{\gamma}}{\gamma-1}$$

The gas within the room remaining after n moles of gas has been pushed into the chamber has undergone an adiabatic reversible expansion, so its entropy change is zero.  Because the room is much larger than the chamber, its temperature changes negligibly when it pushed gas into the chamber through the valve.  So, we conclude that the overall change in entropy for the process is the same as that for the chamber.

Comment: Supplemental: If allowed, reversible temperature equilibration back to $T_\mathrm{ext}$ ultimately brings the total entropy increase to a tidy $P_\mathrm{ext}V_\mathrm{injected}/T_\mathrm{ext}$.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I don't follow.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: As you demonstrated, the gas that the atmosphere pushed into the originally empty container is now warmer because of the work done on it. Unless the container is immediately covered with an adiabatic cap, the gas will now cool back to atmospheric temperature. That irreversible cooling generates entropy $\Delta S = P_\mathrm{ext}V_\mathrm{injected}/T_\mathrm{ext}-nc_P\ln\gamma$, giving a total final entropy increase of $P_\mathrm{ext}V_\mathrm{injected}/T_\mathrm{ext}$, as ManRow calculated. This reconciles the various processes discussed on this page, all starting and ending at the same state.

Comment: I totally disagree.  The cause of the increase in entropy of the gas that has entered the empty container is viscous dissipation within the valve.  If the valve is now closed and the gas within the container is allowed to equilibrate with the surroundings, an amount of heat equal to $nC_v(T-T_{ext})$ will flow from the gas in the chamber to the surroundings, and the gas in the chamber will experience a decrease in entropy of $nC_v\ln{\gamma}}$ while the surroundings experiences an increase in entropy of $nC_v(\gamma-1)$

Comment: So the increase in entropy of the surroundings for this subsequent step will be $\frac{P_{ext}V}{T_{ext}}\frac{1}{\gamma}$ while the gas in the chamber experiences a corresponding decrease of $\frac{P_{ext}V}{T_{ext}}\frac{\ln{\gamma}}{\gamma(\gamma-1)}$

Comment: You’ve introduced closure of a valve that prevents pressure equilibration as the container gas cools. This isn’t mentioned in the original question. The calculations look reasonable.

Comment: Yes.  Otherwise there is additional flow into the chamber as the gas cools.